# Correspondence between time series models in continuous vs. discrete time

Tags: time-series, references, stochastic-processes, finance, continuous-time

I am interested in an overview over the connection and correspondence between time series models in continuous vs. discrete time in finance. E.g. take ARMA(p,q) or GARCH(s,r) or ARMA(p,q)-GARCH(s,r) from discrete time, list their counterparts in continuous time and show how they are related (e.g. how a continuous time process is a limit for the discrete time process as observation frequency increases without bound, or something like that); and do the same with the popular continuous time models (whatever these are) giving their discrete-time counterparts. It could be a full answer with worked out examples or just a reference to a textbook or a paper.

Comment: Related: [What are good references to jump from discrete to continuous time series models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28714/what-are-good-references-to-jump-from-discrete-to-continuous-time-series-models).

Comment: A continuous ARMA is CARMA; see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.5978).

Comment: @corey979, thanks for the reference! I knew the model existed but never had the time to explore it deeper, which is (a small) part of the reason why I am asking the question. Does the paper show the connection between the discrete and the continuous case, or does it treat the continuous case alone?

Comment: I asked about how to discretize stochastic volatility diffusions using the Euler method a while back: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845825/discretizing-a-stochastic-volatility-sde/3070624#3070624